# C++ libpng into GLFWimage into GLFWcursor causing distortion and intermittent behaviour

Tags: c++, image, opengl, glfw, libpng

**EDIT:**

I am now using Brett's code to load a png and it works fine when rendered to a texture in opengl (as a software cursor) but every time I load as a GLFWcursor I get a distorted image (different each time) and there is a problem where the GLFWcursor will only use the last GLFWimage loaded. The pixels I put in are not the pixels I get out.

**EDIT:**

```
GLFWimage CursorManager::LoadImageFromFile(string filename)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
   if (!file) {
     //return NULL;
   }
    unsigned int width = 0;
    unsigned int height = 0;
    unsigned char* buffer = NULL;

    int error = png_rgba_load(file
    ,&width
    ,&height
    ,&buffer);

    if(error == 0)
    {
        GLFWimage image;

        int w = 32; //32
        int h = 32; //32
        unsigned char pixels[w * h * 4];
        memcpy(pixels, buffer, sizeof(pixels));

        //for(int i=0;i<sizeof(pixels);i++)
        //  cout << pixels[i];

        cout << "unsigned char pixels:" << endl;

        for(int i=0;i<sizeof(pixels);i++)
            cout << hex((int)pixels[i]);

        cout << endl << "image.pixels:" << endl;

        image.width = w;
        image.height = h;
        image.pixels = pixels;

        for(int i=0;i<sizeof(image.pixels);i++)
            cout << hex((int)image.pixels[i]);

        return image;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR @ png_rgba_load" << endl;
        //return NULL;
    }
    fclose(file);
        //if (fclose(file) != 0) /* filesystem I/O error (?) */
    //    goto fail;
}
```

-

```
cout << "Loading GLimage " << m_sFileName_Arrow << endl;
m_oArrow     = LoadImageFromFile(m_sFileName_Arrow);
cout << "Loading GLimage " << m_sFileName_Text << endl;
m_oText      = LoadImageFromFile(m_sFileName_Text);
cout << "Loading GLimage " << m_sFileName_Crosshair << endl;
m_oCrosshair = LoadImageFromFile(m_sFileName_Crosshair);
cout << "Loading GLimage " << m_sFileName_Hand << endl;
m_oHand      = LoadImageFromFile(m_sFileName_Hand);
cout << "Loading GLimage " << m_sFileName_Hresize << endl;
m_oHresize   = LoadImageFromFile(m_sFileName_Hresize);
cout << "Loading GLimage " << m_sFileName_Vresize << endl;
m_oVresize   = LoadImageFromFile(m_sFileName_Vresize);
```

-

```
    cout << "Set cursor to Crosshair" << endl;
    cur = glfwCreateCursor(&m_oCrosshair,0,0);
```

the cursor loads from the GLFWimage loaded from libpng, but (1) it has random pixels different each time. (2) Also, no matter what image I set as the new cursor, it always displays the last one loaded, which is m_oVresize (3) when printing image.pixels as hex after setting to pixels it does not match pixels

> unsigned char pixels:
>   00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FFD97400FF272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FFD97400FFD97400FFD97400FF272D70FF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FFD97400FFD97400FFD97400FFD97400FFD97400FF272D70FF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF272D70FF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FFD97400FFD97400FFD97400FFD97400FFD97400FF272D70FF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FFD97400FFD97400FFD97400FF272D70FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FFD97400FF272D70FF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000272D70FF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   image.pixels: 0000000000000000

Comment: Where does the segfault occur?

Comment: because GLFW crash when I set pixels to image_data but I dont know how to convert png_byte to char

Comment: Prior to `glTexImage2D`, you might try: `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`

Comment: I have update the code to show the non opengl version only, but thank you for the pointer Brett.

Comment: There are some problems here. Your use of the `setjmp` call is problematic if it occurs during `png_read_image` - memory will never be released. I'm also not convinced you've setup the code to *force* conversion to an RGBA structure.

Comment: @CHris: according to the GLFW docs, setting the cursor expects an image in RGBA 8 bit per channel format without any padding. In your code, it will depend on the file if you will get a suitable format or not. IIRC, with libpng, you can also define some input transformations, so that it will convert the data automatically to the required format if it differs from what is stored in the file.

Comment: You are setting `image.pixels` to a block of memory that you then free before returning.

Comment: not sure how to memset to char array from png_byte, and I wasn't aware it required RGBA 8bit. Thank you. @Brett can you suggest an alternative to setjmp? please ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably bordering on too much of a code dump for S.O., but it might be full of useful hints to others. It was torture trying to read through the PNG API and various examples, etc. In the end, this is the (relatively) simple interface I provided:

(as for 'copyright' - do whatever you want with it, as long as you leave me alone, etc.)

```
/*******************************************************************************
*
* png_rgba.h : PNG file I/O in (8) bits per channel RGBA format:
*
* Copyright (c) Brett Hale 2008, 2012. Public Domain.
*
*******************************************************************************/


#ifndef _PNG_RGBA_H
#define _PNG_RGBA_H

#if defined (__cplusplus) /* ISO C declaration scope: */

#define _PNG_RGBA_INIT_DECL extern "C" {
#define _PNG_RGBA_FINI_DECL }

#else

#define _PNG_RGBA_INIT_DECL
#define _PNG_RGBA_FINI_DECL

#endif /* defined (__cplusplus) */


#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h> /* ISO C : standard I/O library. */


_PNG_RGBA_INIT_DECL


/******************************************************************************/

/* load a PNG image using an opened file stream. return the image data
 * as a (malloc) allocated RGBA image buffer, with the width: (w), and
 * height: (h). return (0) on success: */

/* if the operation fails, then the dimensions are set to (0), and the
 * buffer is set to (NULL). */

/* the operation fails if the image has zero area, or if the number of
 * pixels exceeds PNG_RGBA_PIXEL_LIMIT. */

/* asserts that 'unsigned int' has a width of at least 32 bits. */


#define PNG_RGBA_PIXEL_LIMIT (0x1000000)

int png_rgba_load (FILE *, unsigned *w, unsigned *h, unsigned char **);


/******************************************************************************/

/* save an RGBA image buffer, with the width: (w), and height: (h), as
 * a PNG image, using an opened file stream. return (0) on success: */

/* the operation fails if the image has zero area, or if the number of
 * pixels exceeds PNG_RGBA_PIXEL_LIMIT. */

/* asserts that 'unsigned int' has a width of at least 32 bits. */


int png_rgba_save (FILE *, unsigned w, unsigned h, const unsigned char *);


/******************************************************************************/


_PNG_RGBA_FINI_DECL


#endif /* _PNG_RGBA_H */
```

And the implementation:

```
/*******************************************************************************
*
* png_rgba.c : PNG file I/O in (8) bits per channel RGBA format:
*
* Copyright (c) Brett Hale 2008, 2012. Public Domain.
*
*******************************************************************************/


#include "png_rgba.h"

#include <png.h> /* PNG library. */


#define PNG_SIG_BYTES (8) /* bytes in the PNG file signature. */


/******************************************************************************/


static int
png_rgba_pixel_limit (png_uint_32 w, png_uint_32 h)
{
    double da;

    /* assert(w != 0 && h != 0); */

    if (w > PNG_RGBA_PIXEL_LIMIT || h > PNG_RGBA_PIXEL_LIMIT)
        return (1); /* since both (w) and (h) are non-zero. */

    /* since an IEEE-754 double has a 53 bit mantissa, it can
     * represent the maximum area: (w * h == 2^48) exactly. */

    da = ((double) w) * ((double) h);

    if (da > ((double) PNG_RGBA_PIXEL_LIMIT))
        return (1);

    return (0); /* the PNG image is within the pixel limit. */
}


/******************************************************************************/


int png_rgba_load
(
    FILE *fp, unsigned *w, unsigned *h, unsigned char **buf)
{
    png_byte magic[PNG_SIG_BYTES]; /* (signature byte buffer) */

    png_structp png_ctx;
    png_infop info_ctx;

    png_uint_32 img_width, img_height, row;
    png_byte img_depth, img_color_type;

    /* 'volatile' qualifier forces reload in setjmp cleanup: */

    png_byte *volatile img_data = NULL;
    png_bytep *volatile row_data = NULL;

    *w = 0, *h = 0, *buf = NULL;


    /* it is assumed that 'longjmp' can be invoked within this
     * code to efficiently unwind resources for *all* errors. */

    /* PNG structures and resource unwinding: */

    if ((png_ctx = png_create_read_struct(
             PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == NULL)
        return (1); /* ENOMEM (?) */

    if ((info_ctx = png_create_info_struct(png_ctx)) == NULL)
    {
        png_destroy_read_struct(& png_ctx, NULL, NULL);
        return (1); /* ENOMEM (?) */
    }

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ctx)) != 0)
    {
        png_destroy_read_struct(& png_ctx, & info_ctx, NULL);
        free(img_data); free(row_data);

        return (1); /* libpng feedback (?) */
    }

    /* check PNG file signature: */

    if (fread(magic, (1), PNG_SIG_BYTES, fp) != PNG_SIG_BYTES)
        png_error(png_ctx, "invalid PNG file");

    if (png_sig_cmp(magic, 0, PNG_SIG_BYTES))
        png_error(png_ctx, "invalid PNG file");


    /* set the input file stream and get the PNG image info: */

    png_init_io(png_ctx, fp);
    png_set_sig_bytes(png_ctx, PNG_SIG_BYTES);

    png_read_info(png_ctx, info_ctx);

    img_width = png_get_image_width(png_ctx, info_ctx);
    img_height = png_get_image_height(png_ctx, info_ctx);

#if (1) /* PNG doesn't support zero area image? */

    if (img_width == 0 || img_height == 0)
        png_error(png_ctx, "zero area PNG image");
#endif

    if (png_rgba_pixel_limit(img_width, img_height))
        png_error(png_ctx, "PNG image exceeds pixel limits");

    img_depth = png_get_bit_depth(png_ctx, info_ctx);
    img_color_type = png_get_color_type(png_ctx, info_ctx);

    /* ignored image interlacing, compression and filtering. */

    /* force 8-bit color channels: */

    if (img_depth == 16)
        png_set_strip_16(png_ctx);

    else if (img_depth < 8)
        png_set_packing(png_ctx);

    /* force formats to RGB: */

    if (img_color_type != PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA)
        png_set_expand(png_ctx);

    if (img_color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE)
        png_set_palette_to_rgb(png_ctx);

    if (img_color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY)
        png_set_gray_to_rgb(png_ctx);

    if (img_color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY_ALPHA)
        png_set_gray_to_rgb(png_ctx);

    /* add full opacity alpha channel if required: */

    if (img_color_type != PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA)
        png_set_filler(png_ctx, 0xff, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);

    /* apply the output transforms before reading image data: */

    png_read_update_info(png_ctx, info_ctx);


    /* allocate RGBA image data: */

    img_data = (png_byte *)
        malloc((size_t) (img_width * img_height * (4)));

    if (img_data == NULL)
        png_error(png_ctx, "error allocating image buffer");

    /* allocate row pointers: */

    row_data = (png_bytep *)
        malloc((size_t) (img_height * sizeof(png_bytep)));

    if (row_data == NULL)
        png_error(png_ctx, "error allocating row pointers");

    /* set the row pointers and read the RGBA image data: */

    for (row = 0; row < img_height; row++)
        row_data[row] = img_data +
            (img_height - (row + 1)) * (img_width * (4));

    png_read_image(png_ctx, row_data);

    /* libpng and dynamic resource unwinding: */

    png_read_end(png_ctx, NULL);
    png_destroy_read_struct(& png_ctx, & info_ctx, NULL);

    free(row_data);

    *w = (unsigned) img_width, *h = (unsigned) img_height;

    *buf = img_data; /* (asserts png_byte is an unsigned char) */

    return (0);
}


/******************************************************************************/


int png_rgba_save
(
    FILE *fp, unsigned w, unsigned h, const unsigned char *data)
{
    png_structp png_ctx;
    png_infop info_ctx;

    png_uint_32 img_width, img_height, row;

    img_width = (png_uint_32) w, img_height = (png_uint_32) h;


    /* it is assumed that 'longjmp' can be invoked within this
     * code to efficiently unwind resources for *all* errors. */

    /* PNG structures and resource unwinding: */

    if ((png_ctx = png_create_write_struct(
             PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == NULL)
        return (1); /* ENOMEM (?) */

    if ((info_ctx = png_create_info_struct(png_ctx)) == NULL)
    {
        png_destroy_write_struct(& png_ctx, NULL);
        return (1); /* ENOMEM (?) */
    }

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ctx)) != 0)
    {
        png_destroy_write_struct(& png_ctx, & info_ctx);

        return (1); /* libpng feedback (?) */
    }


    /* set the output file stream and set the PNG image HDR: */

    png_init_io(png_ctx, fp);

    if (png_rgba_pixel_limit(img_width, img_height))
        png_error(png_ctx, "PNG image exceeds pixel limits");

    png_set_IHDR(
        png_ctx, info_ctx, img_width, img_height, (8),
        PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB_ALPHA, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
        PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT);


    /* write the RGBA image data from the bottom to top row: */

    png_write_info(png_ctx, info_ctx);

    for (row = img_height; row != 0; row--)
    {
        png_bytep row_data = (png_bytep)
            (data + (row - 1) * (img_width * (4)));

        png_write_row(png_ctx, row_data); /* non-interlaced. */
    }

    /* libpng and dynamic resource unwinding: */

    png_write_end(png_ctx, NULL);
    png_destroy_write_struct(& png_ctx, & info_ctx);

    return (0); /* (much easier when the data format is known) */
}


/******************************************************************************/

#if (0)

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* test the ability to read any PNG file and save as RGBA: */

    FILE *ifile = NULL, *ofile = NULL;
    int load_error, save_error;

    unsigned int img_width, img_height;
    unsigned char *img_data = NULL;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "png_rgba <infile> <outfile>\n");
        return (1);
    }

    if ((ifile = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL)
        goto fail;

    load_error = png_rgba_load(
        ifile, & img_width, & img_height, & img_data);

    if (fclose(ifile) != 0) /* filesystem I/O error (?) */
        goto fail;

    if (load_error)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not load '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return (1);
    }

    if ((ofile = fopen(argv[2], "wb")) == NULL)
        goto fail;

    save_error = png_rgba_save(
        ofile, img_width, img_height, img_data);

    if (fclose(ofile) != 0) /* filesystem I/O error (?) */
        goto fail;

    if (save_error)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not save '%s'\n", argv[2]);
        return (1);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "%u x %u image\n", img_width, img_height);
    return (0);

fail:

    perror("png_rgba"); /* prepend to the system error message. */
    return (1);
}

#endif

/******************************************************************************/
```

Most implementations of malloc will yield 8 byte alignment at a minimum - and usually 16 byte alignment on platforms like x86[-64]. For OpenGL, it's therefore safe to assume that rows are 4 byte (RGBA) aligned, *in practice*. This is the default for `glPixelStore` - if in doubt, use:

`glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` prior to `glTexImage2D` calls.

Comment: this works but for some reason I see random pixels appear at the bottom of the cursor, different each time. I also have a problem with the same image always being shown when trying to set the cursor to different stored images.

Comment: i dont think its anything to do with your code though so +1

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the pixel data of a PNG with [Soil](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html).

I used it for setting up a window icon, but according to the [cursor specification](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#cursor_custom), this method should work there also.

```
GLFWimage icons[1];
icons[0].pixels = SOIL_load_image("icon.png", &icons[0].width, &icons[0].height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
glfwSetWindowIcon(window.window, 1, icons);
SOIL_free_image_data(icons[0].pixels);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this just prior to png_read_image():

```
png_set_expand(png_ptr);       // expand to RGB or RGBA
png_set_add_alpha(png_ptr, filler, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);
//"filler" contains the alpha value to assign to each pixel.
```

It's safe to do this even when your image is already RGB or RGBA.
Use filler=255 if you are writing an 8-bit-per-sample image and
you want the pixels to be opaque.

Comment: Error: too few arguments to function ‘void png_set_add_alpha(png_structp, png_uint_32, int)’ (controls)

Answer (score 0):

If loading png images into textures is the only thing you need to do, I suggest maybe ditching libpng and using [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) instead. It's a very simple to use, header-only library that can give you raw RGB data from PNGs.

Comment: Loading images is not the problem, Brett posted some great code which improves upon what I was using already. The problem is that once the image is loaded, converted to GLFWimage and in turn loaded as a GLFWcursor, the image is distorted as a cursor, sometimes it is repeated four times twice horizontally and twice vertically, with a different offset each time and random pixels altered, meaning that the problem is the image becomes distorted when it is loaded as a cursor inside GLFW.

Comment: what I put into GLFW cursor, is not what I get out of it. I either need someone to try themselves and confirm that they have the same problem providing its a problem with GLFW or validate my implementation is invalid.